# How can I define Content-type in Swift using NSURLSession

Tags: web-services, swift

I want to set content-type in my below code to call web api.
Content-type will be  `application/json; charset=utf-8`

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http:/api/jobmanagement/PlusContactAuthentication?email=\(usr)&userPwd=\(pwdCode)")

println("URL:  \(url)")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data, response, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

//  task.setValue(<#value: AnyObject?#>, forKey: <#String#>)
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want to set the `Content-Type` of the request, you can create your own `URLRequest`, supplying your URL, specify the `Content-Type` header using `setValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)` and then issue the request with the `URLRequest` instead of the `URL` directly. And just set the `httpBody` to be that JSON and specify the `httpMethod` of `POST`:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api/jobmanagement/PlusContactAuthentication")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  // the request is JSON
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")        // the expected response is also JSON
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let dictionary = ["email": username, "userPwd": password]
request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")                                 // handle network error
        return
    }

    // parse response; for example, if JSON, define `Decodable` struct `ResponseObject` and then do:
    //
    // do {
    //     let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    //     print(responseObject)
    // } catch let parseError {
    //     print(parseError)
    //     print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))   // often the `data` contains informative description of the nature of the error, so let's look at that, too
    // }
}
task.resume()
```

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27042176/7).

Comment: @Rob, do you know if there is something similar to NSJSonSerialization but for content type "application-javascript"?

Comment: That doesn't compute. What is this `application/javascript` request supposed look like? I associate that `Content-Type` with a script file sitting on the server, not a request from the client.

Comment: This works for me provided I remove `; charset=utf-8` from the string.

Comment: @Rob is `request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")` really required?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale - No, it's generally not needed, but is best practice to include it, to make it explicit what sort of response you are expecting. And, if you have a web service capable of sending back responses in different formats (such as a simple ASP.NET MVC web service), it's important to include this, so the web service knows whether to deliver XML or JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in developing an iOS application using SWIFT 5 for API calls.  The GET method worked fine without these 2 lines. The PUT and the POST methods would send the values to the API server, but once it reached the server it couldn't interpret the JSON data, so my database would insert NULL values for all of the fields.  After adding these 2 lines, the data was transferred into the tables correctly. Hopefully, this saves someone else time.

```
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Comment: The [media type "application/json"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-11) does not have parameters. Compliant recipients should ignore parameters which are not defined. Note that JSON is a binary format. It can be encoded in any of the Unicode Transformation Formats, where UTF-8 is the most commonly used.