# Http post request works fine in postman but not in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, restkit

I'm using RestKit to making network request. I'm using basic auth. I'm trying to make post call to server. It's giving me 401 error. But i took same request body and header tried same request in postman and It's working fine.

code in swift

```
  let requestMapping: RKObjectMapping = self.defineSyncUserProfileRequestMapping().inverseMapping()
        objectManager.addRequestDescriptor(RKRequestDescriptor(mapping: requestMapping, objectClass: UserProfile.self, rootKeyPath: nil, method: RKRequestMethod.POST))

        let responseMapping = self.defineSyncUserProfileResponseMapping() as RKDynamicMapping

        let responseDesriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: responseMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.POST, pathPattern: HabitsConstants.WebServicePath.POST_USER_PROFILE, keyPath: "", statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(UInt(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)))

        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(responseDesriptor)

        objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON
        self.objectManager.HTTPClient .setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername(self.userCredential.username, password: self.userCredential.password)
        self.objectManager.HTTPClient.setDefaultHeader("Content-type" , value: RKMIMETypeJSON)
        RKMIMETypeSerialization.registerClass(RKNSJSONSerialization.self, forMIMEType: "text/json")


        objectManager.postObject(userProfile, path: URL, parameters: nil,
                                 success:{ operation, mappingResult in
                                    let response: NSArray = mappingResult.array()
                                    if response.count > 0 {
                                        if (response.objectAtIndex(0) .isKindOfClass(Error)) {
                                            let error: Error = response.objectAtIndex(0) as! Error
                                            NSLog("ERROR \(error.errorReason)");
                                            self.delegate?.handleMessage(MessageType.ERROR, data: 1.0,errorMessage: error.errorReason)
                                        } else if (response.objectAtIndex(0) .isKindOfClass(UserCredentialResponse)) {
                                            NSLog("Saved profile for user\(userProfile.userId)");
                                            self.getUserProfile()
                                            self.getUserTargets()
                                        }
                                    }

            },
                                 failure:{ operation, error in
                                    NSLog("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                    self.delegate?.handleMessage(MessageType.UNKOWN_ERROR, data: 1.0,errorMessage: "")
            }
        )
```

post man code

```
POST /dmanager/v5/updateprofile/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic aHNoc25hbmE4MjMxOmpzanNqc2pzampz
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 23a32222-db02-b8bb-63cb-da5faffc27be
{"age":23,"phone_number":"","user_id":19709,"weight":25,"key":"jsjsjsjsjjs","set_first_login":"true","first_name":"Suisse","height":91.44,"last_name":"","email":"hshsnana@jsjsja.com","gender":"M"}
```

Comment: You may need to show your code in Swift, and potentially "the one" in POSTMan. We can't guess what's wrong without seeing code.

Comment: @Larme I added code in swift and postman

Comment: I suggest to use Charles Proxy for checking what exactly you sending. https://www.charlesproxy.com. And from your code I see you register serialiser for `text/json` but not `application/json`. Are you sure that it's correct?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Request body from Swift was identical to the Postman request and I was getting Bad Request responses from the Django Rest Framework API host.

Postman adds the `Content-Type` header with value `application/json` if that's the body type you've indicated. I tried setting it myself from within my Swift iOS request client (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27042176/8954127) FMI) and I'm now getting successful responses.

The relevant snippet I used:

```swift
var request = URLRequest(url:renderedUrl)
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```